# iText 7 - Embedding Helvetica to PDF/A-3 upon conversion

Tags: c#, itext7

I'm trying to use iText 7 in C# to convert HTMl to PDF/A-3U, which by specification requires me to embed every font.

With that information, I create a font provider to use in converter properties:

```
var fs = new iText.Layout.Font.FontProvider();

fs.AddDirectory("assets/fonts"); // every font I could imagine stored in .ttfs

var font = PdfFontFactory.CreateRegisteredFont("Helvetica", PdfEncodings.WINANSI, PdfFontFactory.EmbeddingStrategy.PREFER_EMBEDDED);
font.SetSubset(false);

fs.AddFont(FontProgramFactory.CreateRegisteredFont("Helvetica"));
```

When calling `HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf`, this is the error message: `All the fonts must be embedded. This one is not: Helvetica`.

OK, so I need to forcefully embed Helvetica for it to work. Changing `PREFER_EMBEDDED` to `FORCE_EMBEDDED` nets this error: `Standard fonts cannot be embedded.`

This is inevitable, because Helvetica is a default font that should be grabbed from a PDF viewer of choice.

Does that mean I cannot create a PDF/A-3 from HTML?